# How should I handle a follow up interview request that has not been scheduled yet

Tags: interviewing, communication, email

I had an interview for a graphic designer position that went very well.  Three business days later, I received an email from the president of the company.  They requested a follow up interview and wanted to know my availability.  I responded within an hour with a few future dates and time slots and thanked him.  That was four days ago and I have yet to hear anything back about the next interview.  Should I do something?

Other info:  The person who interviewed me was CC'd on the president's email to me, but I didn't realize this until after I sent my response so they were not included.  But I do have my interviewer's contact information if that changes anything.

Answer (score 5):

In case you did "reply" instead of "reply all", please re-send the same email with ALL the original recipients, marked accordingly ("to" or "cc").

That said, you can also call the previous interviewer and check about any possible updates (unless the dates you suggested are far away - which can delay the response from their side).

Answer (score 1):

Reply all to the email letting them know that you're following up and provide them with your availability.

While landing this job is probably your top priority, hiring you is probably not the president's top priority and chances are they've been too busy to respond.